# If $R = GF(3)[x]$, and $I = R{\langle p(x)\rangle}$ where $p(x)$ is irreducible, then $R/I$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If $R = GF(3)[x]$, that is the set of all polynomials with coefficients in $\{0,1,2\}$
and $I = R{\langle x^3+1\rangle}$, the ideal of $R$ generated by $x^3+1$, then show that the factor ring $R/I$ is a field.

I have found that $R/I = \{a+bx + cx^2 + I\ | \ a,b,c \in R\}$, how can I show that this is a field?

Am I correct in saying $0+I$ is the additive identity and $1+I$ is the multiplicative identity?

It is easy to find an additive inverse,  but how can I prove there is a multiplicative inverse?

EDIT: I have changed the polynomial which is generating the ideal, thanks to @Robert Shore for pointing this out.

Comment: An idea is to prove that $I$ is a maximal ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The claim (as originally written) is false.  In $R/I, (x+1)(x^2-x+1)=x^3+1=0$, so $R/I$ can't be a field because it has zero divisors.

If $p(x)$ is irreducible and $p(x), q(x)$ are relatively prime (so that $[q(x)] \neq 0$ in $R/I$, then via long division $[q(x)]$ has an $R/I$-representative such that $\deg q(x) \lt \deg p(x)$.  Continue using the Euclidean algorithm to show that $1 \in \langle p(x), q(x) \rangle$ because $1$ is some $K[x]$-linear combination $a(x) p(x) + b(x) q(x)=1$.  Then $[b(x)]$ is the $R/I$-multiplicative inverse of $[q(x)]$.

Comment: I think I prefer the factorisation $x^3+1=(x+1)^3$. ;-)

Comment: @ancientmathematician In that base field, yes, but my factorization works in any base field.

Comment: That was my mistake, I had to find a cubic polynomial with no roots but clearly $x^3+1$ is not irreducible. Suppose there was an irreducible polynomial there, how would I go about proving $R/I$ is a field? I have changed the question in light of this. This was very tardy on my part I apologise.

Comment: @JohnDoe There is a general theorem that states the following: Let R be a commutative ring with Identity and I be an ideal in R. Then the factor ring R/I is a field if and only if I is maximal. If you look at the proof of that theorem it could be helpful. Also, in principal ideal domains, irreducible/prime ideals are maximal.